# Switching the order of LI elements with CSS only

Tags: css

I need to update an existing page with CSS already in place. I am NOT allowed to touch the existing HTML. My only option is to create another CSS/CSS3 codes to override the existing one. No JS. No JQuery.

Below is a sample existing HTML.  My target output is to create a CSS/CSS3 code override to reverse the position, bringing the "second" class up to be the first in the order list.

I started googling about this but i couldn't find any good resources.  So I just thought that there might be a CSS3 code that could do this like the CSS Code that I imagined below:

HTML:

```
<ul id="mainList">
    <li class="first">i am first</li>
    <li class="second">i am second</li>
    <li class="third">i am third</li>
</ul>
```

Out of this world CSS Code:

```
.second {
    list-position: rank(1);
}
.first {
    list-position: rank(2);
}
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Fiddle here -> http://jsfiddle.net/philcyb/mL41up6t/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could make the children `li` elements [flexbox items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and then use the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) to change the visual order of the element(s).

In this case, you could give the second element an `order` value of `-1` so that it appears first.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wc1Lut6k/)

```css
#mainList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.second {
    order: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mainList">
    <li class="first">I am first</li>
    <li class="second">I am second</li>
    <li class="third">I am third</li>
</ul>
```

Browser support can be [found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). You tagged your question with [css3](/questions/tagged/css3), so I doubt browser support is a concern considering it is currently at about ~93.03% for flexboxes.

---

As a side note, you can also make use of `:nth-child`/`:nth-of-type` in order to select the `li` element by its index rather than using classes.

```css
#mainList {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#mainList li:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="mainList">
    <li>I am first</li>
    <li>I am second</li>
    <li>I am third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution that I've been looking for.  Yes, the solution I need accepts CSS3.  Thank you so much!  

Voting this one as the answer.  Good day!

Answer (score 2):

Josh answer is perfect! Just an additional note that I've used just now: for mobile devices (such as iphone) and other browsers compatibility, I added the below CSS codes to make it work more compatibly.

```
#mainList {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box; 
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column !important;
}
#mainList li:nth-of-type(2) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
#mainList li:nth-of-type(1) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
```